# Subject pronoun or object pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, objects

Here is a sentence:

> Everyone likes you but her/she.

What should be the correct pronoun? According to me since we are replacing a subject with a pronoun it should be *she*, but the answer according to my book is *her*. Could anyone explain the reason for using *her* in this sentence?

Comment: "But" is a preposition here meaning except.  "Her" is the object of that preposition, so the objective case is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by deadrat is correct in saying that **but** acts as a preposition, synonymous with *except* in this instance.

> Everyone likes you **but** her.
>
> Everyone likes you *except* her.

If you want to see it act as a subject, you would need a verb. At that point, **but** becomes a conjugation and the start of a clause.

> Everyone likes you, but she doesn't.
>
> Everyone likes you, but she avoids you.